# Is there an option in sipp to use tls version 1.2

Tags: testing, networking, sip, tls1.2

I am using SIPp software to test some of the TLS 1.2 related code flow in an SBC. I configured the SBC to use TLS v1.2. But whenever I run SIPp client with tls, it exits with the error "Returning EPIPE on invalid socket: 0x1e73060".
Searching EPIPE error yields that the connection is terminated on the remote end. Also, on the traces it is seen that for the Client Hello, the TLS protocol version used is 1.0. Whenever I change the configuration on the SBC to use TLSv1.0, everything works fine. Is there an option, either compile time or run-time, to set the TLS version in SIPp ?

SIPp version used is 3.3

Comment: What, specifically, do you mean by the term, "sipp?" Are you referring to the former name for IPv6? Do you Mean SIP (Session Initiation Protocol? Do you mean SIPp?

Comment: SIPp is the network testing tool for SIP application protocol.

Comment: SIPp uses OpenSSL. What version of OpenSSL do you have? TLS 1.2 was added in OpenSSL 1.0.1 I believe.

Comment: OpenSSL> version
OpenSSL 1.0.1e-fips 11 Feb 2013

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Navigate to SIPp "src" directory. In "socket.cpp" file change TLS version from TLSv1_method() to TLSv1_2_method() and compile the SIPp again.

Comment: Thank you!  This solved my issue.  I have Asterisk using the PJSIP module and pointed to tlsv1_2.  SIPp would not connect and Asterisk kept rejecting the Client Hello handshake because it was looking for tls 1.0.  You are a life saver!

Answer (score 0):

In the latest tar.gz available for SIPp 3.3, the changes need to be made in the sipp.cpp file. As mentioned above, change from TLSv1_method() to TLSv1_2_method().
After this, go ahead and re-compile sipp.

```
    static ssl_init_status FI_init_ssl_context (void)
    {
        sip_trp_ssl_ctx = SSL_CTX_new( TLSv1_2_method() );
        if ( sip_trp_ssl_ctx == NULL ) {
            ERROR("FI_init_ssl_context: SSL_CTX_new with TLSv1_2_method failed");
            return SSL_INIT_ERROR;
        }

        sip_trp_ssl_ctx_client = SSL_CTX_new( TLSv1_2_method() );
        if ( sip_trp_ssl_ctx_client == NULL)
        {
            ERROR("FI_init_ssl_context: SSL_CTX_new with TLSv1_2_method failed");
            return SSL_INIT_ERROR;
        }
```